# Какая кодировка файла на этом скриншоте GVim Win?

Tags: кодировка, vim

[image: Скриншот с кодировкой]

Этот же файл открывается нормально в Mac Gvim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если на маке gvim открывает файл корректно, вы можете узнать кодировку при помощи

```
:set encoding
```

и/или

```
:set fileencoding
```

---

Другой вопрос — как *установить* эту кодировку в vim'е. Если она так просто не устанавливается, возможно, *внутренняя* кодировка vim'а не Unicode. Попробуйте установить `:set encoding=utf-8` и переоткрыть файл.

Comment: Спасибо. `set:` без аргументов показывает, в числе прочего, `fileencoding=utf-16le
  fileencodings=ucs-bom,utf-8,default,latin1
  fileformats=unix,dos,mac`.

Comment: Предыдущий комментарий относился к мак gvim. `set:` на win не показывает `fileencoding`. `set: fileencoding` показывает `filencoding=` и ждет кодировку. `set: fileencodings` покзывает `fileencodings=ucs-bom`. Не понятно, как отобразить файл в читабельном виде.

Comment: @user3156459: А что показывает `set encoding?`?

Comment: @user3156459: Вангую `latin1`.

Comment: `:set encoding` -> `encoding=cp1251`

Comment: [Здесь](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5166652/how-to-view-utf-8-characters-in-vim-or-gvim) обсуждается похожая проблема. Включил в _vimrc следующее и файл стал читабельным.
    `set enc=utf-8
    set fileencoding=utf-8
    set fileencodings=ucs-bom,utf8`
Вы выше говорили о внутренней кодировке. Что это и как она отличается от, если такая есть, внешей?

Comment: @user3156459: enc — внутренняя, в которой vim держит символы. fenc — внешняя, в которой символы содержатся в файле.

Answer (score 2):

Смешно. Вы бы ещё спросили, что тут написано. :)

Попробуйте воспользоваться [сервисом](http://foxtools.ru/Text), определяющим кодировку текста.

Comment: Вопрос был слишком лаконичен, вероятно. Хотелось получить помощи по функциям самого GVim по определению кодировки файла.
На маке GVim сам распознает что-то и показывает `converted` и файл читабельный.

Включил вот этот код в `_vimrc` но ни одна из перекодировок не помогает:set wcm=<Tab>
    menu Encoding.koi8-r :e ++enc=koi8-r ++ff=unix<CR>
    menu Encoding.windows-1251 :e ++enc=cp1251 ++ff=dos<CR>
    menu Encoding.cp866 :e ++enc=cp866 ++ff=dos<CR>
    menu Encoding.utf-8 :e ++enc=utf8 <CR>
    menu Encoding.koi8-u :e ++enc=koi8-u ++ff=unix<CR>